# TheGui instance has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, tkinter, explorer

We are making a program to paste one image ontop of another image. Our problem is trying to store the filename. We have an explorer function that stores the file path into a variable wow and wink. We then run the program and get the error:

```
AttributeError: TheGui instance has no attribute 'read'
```

Here is our code:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess
import sys
import tkFileDialog
import PIL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # single use of plt is commented out
import os.path  
import PIL.ImageDraw        
import PIL.Image

bg_size   = [1080,1920]
logo_size = [200,200]
seal_size = [200,200]


seal = 0


class TheGui:
    global wow
    global wink

    wow = ""
    wink = ""

    global in_path
    global in_path1
    def __init__(self, parent):
        #------- frmSetup ----------#
        self.frmSetup = Frame(parent, bd=5)
        self.frmSetup.pack()

        self.inChoices = ('Text', 'Midi')
        self.varRadio = IntVar()

        self.r1 = Radiobutton(self.frmSetup, text="Convert Text INPUT into Midi OUTPUT",
            variable=self.varRadio, value=0, command=self.selRadio)
        self.r1.pack(anchor=W)

        self.r2 = Radiobutton(self.frmSetup, text="Convert Midi INPUT into Text OUTPUT", 
            variable=self.varRadio, value=1, command=self.selRadio)
        self.r2.pack(anchor=W)
        #------- frmSetup ----------#

        sep = Frame(parent, width=1, bd=5, bg='black')
        sep.pack(fill=X, expand=1)

        #------- frmIn ----------#
        # http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm
        self.frmIn = Frame(parent, bd=5)         
        self.frmIn.pack()

        self.lblIn = Label(self.frmIn, text='Campaign Background', width=20)
        self.lblIn.pack(side=LEFT) 

        self.inFilePath = StringVar() # http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm
        self.entIn = Entry(self.frmIn, width=20, textvariable=self.inFilePath)
        self.entIn.pack(side=LEFT)


        self.btnIn = Button(self.frmIn, text='Browse', command=self.OpenExplorer)
        self.btnIn.pack(side=LEFT) 
        #------- frmIn ----------#


        #------- frmOut ----------#
        self.frmOut = Frame(parent, bd=5)
        self.frmOut.pack()

        self.lblOut = Label(self.frmOut, text='Logo Path', width=20)
        self.lblOut.pack(side=LEFT) 

        self.outFilePath = StringVar()
        self.entOut = Entry(self.frmOut, width=20, textvariable=self.outFilePath)
        self.entOut.pack(side=LEFT) 

        self.btnOut = Button(self.frmOut, text='Browse', command=self.OpenExplorer1)
        self.btnOut.pack(side=LEFT) 
        #------- frmOut ----------#

        sep = Frame(parent, width=1, bd=5, bg='black')
        sep.pack(fill=X, expand=1)

        #------- frmButtons ----------#
        self.frmOut = Frame(parent, bd=5)
        self.frmOut.pack()

        self.btnConvert = Button(self.frmOut, 
            text='Convert', command=self.test(wow,wink))
        self.btnConvert.pack() 

    #------- handle commands ----------#
    def selRadio(self):
        self.lblIn.config(text = self.inChoices[self.varRadio.get()] 
            + ' Input File Path')
        self.lblOut.config(text = self.inChoices[(self.varRadio.get()+1)%2] 
            + ' Output File Path')
        print str(self.varRadio.get())

    def btnInBrowseClick(self):             
        rFilepath = askopenfilename(defaultextension='*', 
            initialdir='.', initialfile='', parent=self.frmIn, title='select a file') 
        self.inFilePath.set(rFilepath)
        print self.entIn.get()

    def btnOutBrowseClick(self):  
        rFilepath = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='*', 
            initialdir='.', initialfile='', parent=self.frmIn, title='select a file') 
        self.outFilePath.set(rFilepath)
        print self.entOut.get()

    def btnConvertClick(self):  
        if self.varRadio.get() == 0:
            inputTextFilePath = str(self.inFilePath.get())
            outputMidiFilePath = str(self.outFilePath.get())
            print 'midi 4 txt', inputTextFilePath, outputMidiFilePath
            midi24txt.mid4txt(inputTextFilePath, outputMidiFilePath)
        else:      
            inputMidiFilePath = str(self.inFilePath.get())
            outputTextFilePath = str(self.outFilePath.get())            
            print 'midi 2 txt', inputMidiFilePath, outputTextFilePath
            midi24txt.mid2txt(inputMidiFilePath, outputTextFilePath)


    def OpenExplorer(self):
        def main():

            Tkinter.Tk().withdraw() # Close the root window
            in_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
            wow = in_path
            print wow , "\n"
            outFilePath.insert(wow)
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            main()
    def OpenExplorer1(self):
        def main():

            Tkinter.Tk().withdraw() # Close the root window
            in_path1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
            wink = in_path1
            print wink , "\n"

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            main()


    def test(main_image, logo_image, self):
        logo = PIL.Image.open(main_image)
        main = PIL.Image.open(logo_image)
        img_w, img_h = main_image.size

        if seal == 0:
            print("We converting a banner its lit")
            offset = (0,780)
            main.paste(logo, offset)
            main.save('out.png')
            main.show()
        else:
            logo.resize(seal_size)
            offset = (0,600)
            print("We are converting a seal over here")



root = Tk()
my_gui = TheGui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Looking at the code, it appears to be a true fact that `TheGUI` doesn't have the attribute `read`. Do  you think it should have that attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem seems to be this line:

```
def test(main_image, logo_image, self):
```

Note that `self` *always* has to be the first parameter, because if you call a method like this

```
self.test(wow,wink)
```

this is equivalent to

```
TheGUI.test(self, wow, wink)
```

The `self` parameter is not special in the sense that Python automatically assigns the current instance to whichever parameter is called `self`. Instead, the current instance is always passed as the *first* parameter (which is called `self` merely by convention). This means, that what you *think* is the `main_image`, actually is `self`, i.e. the current instance of your UI class.

---

Which brings us to the next problem. In this line:

```
self.btnConvert = Button(self.frmOut, 
    text='Convert', command=self.test(wow,wink))
```

you execute the function `self.test(wow,wink)` *once* when you *create* the button and then assign to `command` the *result* of that invocation. Instead, you have to create an anonymous function:

```
self.btnConvert = Button(self.frmOut, 
    text='Convert', command=lambda: self.test(wow,wink))
```

---

Another problem: The way you use `global` inside the class does not work. This will *not* make the `wow` and `wink` variables "static" in a Java-way. If you want to use `global`, you have to put it into every method that uses those variables. Instead, I would suggest making those variables of the instance, i.e. `self.wow` and `self.wink`:

```
self.btnConvert = Button(self.frmOut, 
            text='Convert', command=self.test(self.wow, self.wink))
```

And accordingly in `OpenExplorer` and the other method:

```
def OpenExplorer(self):
    Tkinter.Tk().withdraw() # Close the root window
    in_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    self.wow = in_path
    print self.wow , "\n"
    outFilePath.insert(self.wow)
```

Also, those methods don't need a `main` method and and `if __name__ == "__main__"` check. This check is not necessary whenever you open a Tkinter window, it's just to see whether the file is executed directly or imported by another script. The way it is now, the UI would not work when imported from another module.

---

Note that I did not try to run your code; those are just the problems that immediately caught my eye. If you experience any follow-up problems, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: I bet this will work! We had the lambda thing a bit ago, but I guess I forgot to put it back in. I will test later in the day. Thank you!

Comment: This didn't work :( I tried putting the variables directly into the function, and now i get the error: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: ''

Comment: @TheGuyWhoCodes See my edit. There was (at least) one other problem.